# Display on page every post in blog WITH comments

Tags: posts, pages, comments

I am trying to create a page which displays **all** the posts in the blog, with the comments to each post listed below the respective post. By looking around the internet I figured out how to create a page template with the following code:

```
  <?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => -1);
$posts= get_posts( $args );
if ($posts) {
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        Echo "<h1>"; the_title(); Echo "</h1>";
        Echo "<p><small>";the_time('jS F Y'); Echo "</small></p>";
        the_content();
    }
}
?>
```

This works and an an happy with it. **But** I am stumped as to how to get the individual post *comments* to appear as well. Everything I have tried so far doesn't work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Link to the source of the code please.

Comment: I'll give you that the formatting of the above code is pretty much s#!t, but why would one have to link to a source, @Brad? (My code's source is mostly my mind. Ain't that linkable...)

Comment: Brad, I took the code from here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/12845351](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12845351) and then butchered it until it served my purposes. I am not a coder by profession.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Add `comments_template();` under your `the_content()`.

But there's a better way to do this that will carry over any formatting and style you have on your main blog. Maybe you don't want this, though, so ignore the rest if needed.

Here's the improved loop code:

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => -1);
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) {

    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        get_template_part('content', get_post_format());
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    get_template_part('content', 'none');
}
```

That is a pretty basic Wordpress loop, nothing really tricky going on and you almost had exactly that with your provided code. Instead of directly outputting the content, this code will load the template parts just like the loop in `index.php`, which should include the call to `comments_template()` if its a half-way decent theme.

Here's the updated improved loop that should work for older themes that do not have `content.php`:

```
if ($query->have_posts()) {

    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        the_content();
        comments_template();
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    echo 'No posts found.';
}
```

But your original code is literally doing the same thing, just organized a bit differently. I would suggest adding a `wp_reset_postdata()` call to your code, though, so you can restore the original query. Probably won't hurt to leave it out, but it'll be a mighty hard bug to track down in the future.

Comment: Your short answer worked great! But, on the other hand, your improved code gave me a page with blog header but no body. Code typo? Your short answer is good enough for me, but if you want to trouble shoot your improved code I will try out any fixes. Otherwise, I'll go with your short answer.

Comment: That probably means your theme doesn't use "template parts," i.e. there is no `content.php` or `content-[POST_TYPE].php`. Its a relatively new addition to Wordpress, so older themes do not use it. No biggie, though, as you can replace my `get_template_part()` function call with `the_content(); comments_template();` and it should work as expected.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I was working with the Wordpress Twenty-ten theme. Your code for older themes did indeed work. Many thanks for your kind help.